# symbol _ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base7_M_hookEPS0_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference

Tags: c++

I compiled the below code on the compilation machine with mentioned configuration. The compilation was successful. But got the above error on executing 
ldd -r my_executable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> mylist;
    mylist.push_back(1);
    mylist.push_back(2);
    mylist.push_back(3);

    cout << "\nList:\n";
    for(list<int>::iterator it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << "\n";
    }
}
```

Compiling machine details:
glibc version  2.14.1 
libstdc++ version GLIBCXX_3.4.16
 (output after running command : strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep LIBCXX )

Target machine details:
glibc version  2.12.90
libstdc++ version GLIBCXX_3.4.14
(output after running command : strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep LIBCXX )

Comment: @usar, you don't need to in C++, there's an implicit `return 0;`

Comment: @Sayali, every version of `libstdc++.so.6` contains `GLIBCXX_3.4`, you need to look for the _newest_ symbol version it contains, not the oldest. You probably don't have a new enough `libstdc++` on the target machine, or you need to read https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths and the docs it links to.

Comment: Open up /usr/include/<GCC Version>/<arch triplet>/bits/c++config.h and look for the definition of the  macro _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION in both the host and build systems. If they're different, there's your problem.

Comment: @themoondothshine, nonsense. That has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Of course it does Mr. Wakely :) list_node_base::_M_hook is defined in that namespace. To make sure there are no version conflicts!

Answer (score 1):

You have built your program on a machine with one version of GCC and so your program depends on the shared libraries from that version of GCC, then you are trying to run it on a machine with an older version of GCC, which does not have the necessary shared libraries.

There are hundreds of answers about this on StackOverflow already. The simplest answer is to just build the program on the target machine, so it is built with the version of GCC that exists on the target machine.